# How to open a Visual Studio project without migrating the solution and project files to a newer version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible to open a Visual Studio 2015 solution in Visual Studio 2017 without the projects being migrated to a newer format?

We have a dependency on Visual Studio 2015, but a user who only has 2017 installed, therefore they cannot poison the repository with 2017 versions of solution and csproj files.

Comment: In my experience 2017 won't migrate the project files (I'm assuming you're referring to csproj) to the new format. It leaves everything as-is. Have you tried it and found that not to be the case?

Comment: @CraigW. I may be wrong, but after opening it automatically opened a migration report, perhaps I was being hasty in assuming it had done anything underneath!

Comment: what kind of project? .NET Core?